Coloris JS - Programmatically change color to random value on load
I am using the Coloris JavaScript library in order to allow the user to select a custom color for an element on the page. I would like to randomly select a color on page load and apply it to the element by default. Here's what I tried so far:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  
  const colorInput = document.querySelector('.instance1');
  const colorSquare = document.querySelector('.custom-color');
  
  Coloris({
    el: '.color-fields'
  });

  Coloris.setInstance('.instance1', {
      themeMode: 'dark',
      closeButton: true,
      onChange: (color) => {
          colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = color;
      }
  });
  
  // Set random color value on load
  colorInput.value = '#'+(0x1000000+Math.random()*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
  
  // Trigger change
  colorInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));

});
.custom-color {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input class="color-fields instance1" type="text" value="green" data-coloris="">
<div class="custom-color"><span>CHANGE COLOR</span></div>



The color picker works when you use it manually and the input value is correctly getting set to a random color, but it doesn't seem to be triggering the change on load. I tried adding colorInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true })); after setting the value to a random color, but that didn't change anything. Any thoughts?

The code you're using is explained in the documentation as:

The color thumbnail is updated when an input event is triggered on the adjacent input field. If you programmatically update the value of the input field, you may need to trigger the event manually using the following code ...

So it will only update the thumbnail, it won't trigger the onChange. ]

Since you already got access to the DOM element, just set the color with style.backgroundColor, just like you're doing it inside the onChange.
If you're going to change the value more often, consider making a separate onColorChange function, which you pass to Coloris and can call by yourself:


const colorInput = document.querySelector('.instance1');
const colorSquare = document.querySelector('.custom-color');

const onColorChange = (color) => {
    colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

Coloris({
    el: '.color-fields',
    themeMode: 'dark',
    closeButton: true,
    onChange: onColorChange
});

// Set random color value on load
const randomColor = '#'+(0x1000000+Math.random()*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
colorInput.value = randomColor;

// Trigger change
onColorChange(randomColor);
colorInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
.custom-color {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input class="color-fields instance1" type="text" value="green" data-coloris="">
<div class="custom-color"><span>CHANGE COLOR</span></div>



